# Options for Loading Fixtures in a Django Database

Tags: database, django, django-fixtures

On https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/, it says to run `manage.py loaddata <fixturename>` to re-load data, or to name a fixture "initial_data" to load it with every migrate.

On the page https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Fixtures, it says that a fixture can be loaded using `python manage.py syncdb`, but it looks like the database has to be reset first (true or false?).

Finally, on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/, it says to use `django-admin.py loaddata <fixturename>` to reload. Are these all options for the same thing? Or what are the differences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two `loaddata` are the same thing, but `syncdb` is a command that creates database tables loads the initial data for that app.

You would use `loaddata` to load a fixture into a database and `syncdb` to set up your database for a new app.

`manage.py` is a wrapper around `django-admin.py` that adds your project to the path and sets up the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable. Normally, you'll use `manage.py` once your project has been set up.